# collector_value Error while Rendering RMarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, rendering, read.csv

Yesterday, I rendered the following code in an RMarkdown file:

```
trip_data_202208 <- read_csv(("/Users/mif06/Documents/
                             Cyclistic/CSV/202208_divvy_tripdata.csv"),
  col_types = cols_only(ride_id = col_character(), 
  rideable_type = col_character(), started_at = col_character(), 
  ended_at = col_character(), 
  total_ride_time = col_time(format = ""), 
  day_of_week = col_character(), 
  start_station_name = col_character(), 
  start_station_id = col_character(), 
  end_station_name = col_character(), 
  end_station_id = col_character(), 
  start_lat = col_double(), 
  start_lng = col_double(), end_lat = col_double(), 
  end_lng = col_double(),member_casual = col_character() 
    )
      )
```

Today, I go back to add to the RMarkdown file and I get the following error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("collector_value") :
no applicable method for 'collector_value' applied to an object of class "c('collector_skip', 'collector')"
```

I'm not sure why I'm having an issue since I rendered the same code before.
I can't even find what this error means. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a solution. I encountered the same error.

```
    tbcmb.data.df <- read_delim(file = file_path,
                              col_select = c(gene, total.counts),
                              show_col_types = FALSE)


Error in UseMethod("collector_value") :                                                                            
      no applicable method for 'collector_value' applied to an object of class "c('collector_skip', 'collector')"
```

Turns out it's because my header was not the required ones. Once I removed all the formatting, I figured the issue.

To debug, I would suggest to comment out all of your formatting and read in the csv file first.

I hope this can be helpful.